# Default Alarm ringtone

Tags: alarm

Es file explorer can set the default ringtone for Alarms (this means that when you set a new alarm, xyz sound is already selected by default).  Factory "default" is set to silent.

Google Assistant will set alarms but uses the factory default sound which sisilent on my phone.

I do not like es file explorer.  Is there a way to manually do this without root just as es file explorer does without root?

Are there other programs that will do this with the system sounds.?

Btw, es file explorer will not do this with system sounds but only with my personal files.  Which is okay but not acceptable.

Comment: [Mixplorer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1523691) is very versatile minus the ES invasive payload

Comment: You can use Solid Xplorer. Alarms from Google also helps. Your alarm would have the same tone which was used in the last alarm. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock&hl=en_US&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dalarm+app+oneplus&pcampaignid=APPU_1_BUx5XIG2JczkvAS1jIKoBw

Comment: thanks for the answers.  Mixplorer did not seem to have anything to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly easiest way for me:

1. Download Zedge. (Free app)
2. Look up what sound you want (it has alot)
3. Set as "alarm sound"
4. It is now Google clock's alarm default

And it also has wallpapers,  ringtones,  notification sounds and so on. You can use them anywhere even Facebook messenger.

Hope this helps :)